# NatTable Cell editing should disable on typing any "regular" characters such as letters or digits

Tags: java, eclipse, nattable

1. I want to UN-register the NatTable cell editing when typing any "regular" characters such as letters or digits.
   i.e. On typing any digit or character nothing to be done.
2. One more question I have registered the TABLE_CYCLE_TRAVERSAL_STRATEGY into my grid layer, work fine with arrow keys and tab as well.
   But when we press the enter key, the cell selection moving into the next cell.

```
gridLayer.registerCommandHandler(new MoveCellSelectionCommandHandler(this.selectionLayer,
new EditTraversalStrategy(ITraversalStrategy.TABLE_CYCLE_TRAVERSAL_STRATEGY, this.natTable)));
```

But I want to implement such a way that, on pressing Enter key, I need to edit a selected cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and register custom configurations.

1. `DefaultEditBindings`
   You need to remove these two configurations to avoid that the edit mode is activated on key press

   ```
   uiBindingRegistry.registerKeyBinding(
           new LetterOrDigitKeyEventMatcher(),
           new KeyEditAction());
   uiBindingRegistry.registerKeyBinding(
           new LetterOrDigitKeyEventMatcher(SWT.MOD2),
           new KeyEditAction());
   ```
2. `DefaultSelectionBindings#configureMoveDownBindings()`
   Remove the following lines to disable the selection movement on ENTER

   ```
   uiBindingRegistry.registerKeyBinding(
           new KeyEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, SWT.CR), action);
   uiBindingRegistry.registerKeyBinding(
           new KeyEventMatcher(SWT.MOD1, SWT.CR), action);
   ```
3. Register the following UI binding to enable editing on ENTER and SHIFT+ENTER

   ```
   uiBindingRegistry.registerKeyBinding(
           new KeyEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, SWT.CR),
           new KeyEditAction());
   uiBindingRegistry.registerKeyBinding(
           new KeyEventMatcher(SWT.MOD1, SWT.CR),
           new KeyEditAction());
   ```

Also you need to ensure that the default configurations are not registered by setting the `useDefaultConfiguration` constructor parameter to `false`. Otherwise the mentioned ui bindings are still registered and triggered (e.g. for the `SelectionLayer` you need a customized `DefaultSelectionLayerConfiguration` that registers the customized `DefaultSelectionBindings`).

Comment: Even after register the custom configuration with point 2 and 3 mentioned in your comment for  selection movement on ENTER . It is still moving the selection on Enter. As i debugged and checked the selection movement is trigging from SelectionLayer.docommand() -> MoveCellSelectionCommandHandler#moveLastSelectedDown

Comment: If I modify the DefaultSelectionBindings like explained above, there is no movement on ENTER. I suppose you missed to disable the default configuration which means the DefaultSelectionBindings are registered by default and additionally your custom configurations. Then the bindings to move the selection are still registered.

Comment: yeah got the solution, we need to unregister the KeyEventMatcher mentioned in point 3 before restringing the custom action.